# Is SignalR a Microsoft only technology?

Tags: c#-4.0, signalr, borland-c++

Can SignalR send messages to a Borland C++ client and if so what is the oldest version of Borland C++ (ver 6/ ver 7)? How would a Borland C++ client receive a SignalR message if it is possible? If not what send technology would be best with Borland C++ as the client and C# .NET as the pusher?

Comment: SignalR definitely related to ASP.NET <http://www.asp.net/signalr> <https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR>    <http://signalr.net/>

Comment: @T.S.: the client side may be something else than a web application. it can also be any .Net client

Comment: @SteveB Client probably doesn't even have to be .net. Rather javascript. I think

Comment: But can it be a Borland C++ client, and if so how would the borland c++ client receive SignalR messages?

Comment: [The documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki#in-depth) states .Net, Javascript or Xamarin client. No C++. What kind of scenario are you targeting? There are plenty of message bus software. SignalR is only one of them and is targeting a specific scenario, where messages are sent over internet or Web applications.

Comment: Really targeting IPC between a C# app and a Borland C++ app on same computer or maybe at most local LAN. I think comment about ZeroMQ is probably best alternative. I have explored using Redis pub/sub also.

Comment: There is a active SignalR c++ client being work - https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp. It may be possible to compile this with Borland C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2346) there is a C++ client, but it's not actively maintained, so you might have to customize a lot of the code to make it work for you. 
It *might* be possible to use node.js/socket.io with [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) but it's probably not very straightforward.
I'd take a look at things like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Comment: Have used ZeroMQ for a couple of C# / PHP projects, is there a ZeroMQ package for Borland C++?

Comment: There appear to be several options for C++, and I would expect they only use standard C++, so it should or at least might work with Borland C++ too. I honestly know next to nothing about Borland; I guess you'll either have to give it a try or ask the maintainers of the relevant project(s).

Answer (score 1):

I am searching for the same info but in a wider context. I m rather interested to know, if there exists a way using SignalR from a plain C++ in general without managed extensions. Compiler as such does not matter for me. I plan using MS Visual Studio 2005 or above.

Originally, I was sure that technology is fully .NET related. To my surprise, I have discovered C++ client wrapper on official ASP.NET source repository. 
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp

The code is for VS 2013. After a short review of code, I see no use of managed extensions or Microsoft specific coding. It looks that the code should be portable with very limited effort. I will try building it now with VS 2005 and will update this comment on results afterwards.

As of the date of writing, last commit into repository is only 15 days old. So it looks like the code is actively maintained and developed.